# 3d surface chart with javascript?

Tags: javascript, charts, 3d

Which 3d surface chart library out there do you recommand? It is ok if it is flash or silverlight, as long as it supports dynamic data update thru json.. Thank you!

Gil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [javascript-surface-plot](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-surface-plot/)?

As for javascript not being fast enough, what do you think this is, 2009?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are after but one option for 3D charting with Javascript would be [Canvas 3D Graph](http://dragan.yourtree.org/code/canvas-3d-graph/)

**Edit**

Surface plotting is quite CPU-intensive and requires a good graphics API, so Javascript doesn't cut it.

Unfortunately there aren't any ready-made 3D charting libraries for Flash or Silverlight that support surface plotting, only a couple of 3D engines, for example [Away3D](http://away3d.com/).

If you are willing to go with applets then [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) might help you ([JFreeChart in an Applet](http://www.codegravity.com/blog/jfreechart-in-an-applet)). You can [control the applet with Javascript](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=16833) and feed it whatever data necessary.

Comment: It doesn't do surface plots though.

Answer (score 0):

Jmol is used in SAGE for 3D graph plotting. It runs as an applet. It is quite heavy-weight, and it even has a console. Check out the SAGE sources for usage.